# Mac OSX Apache Write Privileges

Tags: php, macos, apache, privileges, chown

So here is my problem. Its started when I discovered that I couldn't install plugins or themes in WordPress from the admin panel, it just kept asking for my connection info ( http://cl.ly/DLdH/o ).

I found a blog post which suggested changing the ownership of the wordpress folder to the Apache user, i.e. _www like so

```
sudo chown -R _www ./
```

That did, partially, fix the problem as I was able to install plugins and themes as well as writing to the directory through PHP which was all good but then I couldn't add/delete/edit any of the files in my text editor or even in Finder. It just keeps asking for my user password in order to process the action.

Changing the ownership back fixes the password issue but then I cant do any writing to the directory though PHP anymore.

Is there a way to allow me do **both** things at the same time?

**EDIT:**

I came across this cmd

```
sudo dscl . -append /Groups/_www GroupMembership [myUsername]
```

which added me i.e. my username to the group _www, then I executed

```
sudo chown -R _www .
sudo chgrp -R _www .
```

then it worked!

Comment: Not the right place for this. Try webmasters.stackexchange...

Comment: Seen far worse questions than this! Thanks for the tip on your fix too, @Taha.

Comment: Warning these commands don't work as stated on Mavericks, made my site unaccessible for myself..

Answer (score 5):

Have the *user* own the files. Change the *group* to `_www`. Give write permission to group.

```
chown -R <username> .
chgrp -R _www .
chmod -R g+w .
```

Comment: doesn't work :( wordpress asks for conn info and php gives permission denied.