# Error when using PHP move_uploaded_file()

Tags: javascript, php, post, xmlhttprequest

I am relatively new to php and I am trying to make use of the move_uploaded_file() function.

I firstly send a HTTP POST request from some javascript/jquery to a php file as follows with an audio blob....my php file is hosted on a microsoft azure server...

```
    mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(e) {

    var fileType = 'audio';
    var fileName = 'test.ogg';

    var formData = new FormData();  
    formData.append(fileType + '-filename', fileName);
    formData.append(fileType + '-blob', e.data); 
    // e.data is the audio blob

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
        console.log('wooo');
    }
    };
    request.open('POST', myserver/Test.php');
    request.send(formData);
    }
```

My PHP code picks up this post request and seems to receive the file with no errors

```
    <?php
    print_r($_FILES);
    $temp = $_FILES['audio-blob']['tmp_name'];
    $name = $_FILES['audio-blob']['name'];


        if (isset($_FILES["audio-blob"])) {

            $fileName = $_POST["audio-filename"];
            $uploadDirectory = 'C:/Users/Liam/PhpRecordings/';

            if (move_uploaded_file($temp, $uploadDirectory . $fileName)) {
              echo("file moved!!!!");
            }
            else
            {
                echo(" problem moving uploaded file");
            }
        }
?>  
<html>
<body>
Test
</body>
</html>

<?
?>
```

However, when trying to move the file it does not succeed and I get the echo

> problem moving uploaded file

The full post response is here

> Array (
>       [audio-blob] => Array
>           (
>               [name] => blob
>               [type] => audio/ogg
>               [tmp_name] => D:\local\Temp\phpA897.tmp
>               [error] => 0
>               [size] => 15755
>           )
>
> )  problem moving uploaded file     Test

Does anybody know why the file move is not occurring?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is there are enough rights for your code to write to `/Users/Liam/PhpRecordings/`?.

Try to run this code and add output into comment for this answer:

```
echo file_put_contents('/Users/Liam/PhpRecordings/test.txt', 'testing_writing_to_file');
```

According to the author's further comments there are problems with write privileges to `$uploadDirectory`. 
There are similar question on SO - [Write permissions on mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8035939/write-privileges-localhost-mac-osx)

Comment: After viewing the properties of the folder it does appear that all "write" rights are selected.

Comment: So your php code can not write to this location. Maybe file system permissions are too strict

Comment: How would I go about allowing my PHP code permissions to the file system?

Comment: There are some questions with answers, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8862345/mac-osx-apache-write-privileges

Comment: In simple case (only for testing on your local machine) you can create folder /www with command `mkdir /www`, then add all rights for it with command `chmod 777 /www` and then try to save your uploaded files into this folder.